# Programmatically get selected layers from the QGIS legend?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

My QGIS plugin exports all layers from QGIS to KML format. Now I'd like to export only selected layers. However, I can't find any hints in QGIS API. Is it possible to iterate over selected layers in the QGIS legend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original question was referred to QGIS 2.x version.

## QGIS 3.x

To get the layers selected in the TOC in QGIS 3.x [check this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274894/4177).

> with the iface object, it is possible to get the layerTreeView, which
>   has a method selectedLayers():
>
> ```
> iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
> ```
>
> more methods on [QgsLayerTreeView in the docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html):

## QGIS 2.x

You can get the layers selected in the TOC with something like this

```
selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers()
```

the `selectedLayers()` method in [QgsLegendInterface](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html) does the trick. But take into account that:

- If a group is selected neither the group itself, neither the layers within are returned by `selectedLayers()`. You must select it in the GUI one by one.
- Probably you want to filter the layers by their type (TileLayer, QgsRasterLayer, QgsVectorLayer, ...)

A more complete example:

```
selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers()
for layer in selectedLayers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        print(layer.name())
    elif layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
        print(layer.name())
    elif layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.PluginLayer:
        print(layer.name())
    else:
        raise Exception('Should never happen')
```

Comment: It doesn't work for QGIS 3.x