# AttributeError when getting selected layers with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, select, attributeerror

How can I get the selected layers in QGIS 3 with PyQGIS?

I tried:

```
selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers()
```

as suggested in [Programmatically get selected layers from the QGIS legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152537/how-to-get-programmatically-selected-layers-from-the-qgis-legend), but it seems that there is an [API breaking change](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html)

> QgsLegendInterface was removed. It was replaced by layer tree API
> (QgsLayerTreeNode class and others). Methods that deal with custom
> actions in main window's layer tree context menu were moved to
> QgisInterface:

I then tried:

```
selectedLayers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().selectedLayers()
```

but I get an error about:

> AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTree' object has no attribute
> 'selectedLayers'

What's the correct way to get the selected layers in QGIS3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the `iface` object, it is possible to get the `layerTreeView`, which has a method `selectedLayers()`:

```
iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
```

More methods on `QgsLayerTreeView` in the docs: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html