# A loop to select all active layers in a project

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to export all active layers in a QGIS project to a specified folder, below is what I get atm

```
Outputdir='C:/Users/DN/Downloads/Test/'


layer = iface.activeLayer()

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer, Outputdir + layer.name() + ".shp", "utf-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", 1)
```

It only works when I click on the layer that I want to export, I am wondering if it's possible to write a loop to loop through all active layers in the project and export them.

Comment: There is only one 'active layer', it's the one you've clicked on. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26257/iterating-over-map-layers-in-qgis-python might help with your problem.

Comment: I wonder if OP means all checked layers... in which case the likely duplicate is: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152537/programmatically-get-selected-layers-from-the-qgis-legend/152544

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over all layers in the project and export them to a specified folder do the following:

We need identify all layers in the project using **iface.mapCanvas().layers()**. Then we can loop over the layers and export them.
**Outputdir** is the name of the folder where you would like to save to.

```
Outputdir = 'C:/temp/'

layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for layer in layers:
    layerType = layer.type()
    if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        print (layer.name())
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer, Outputdir + layer.name() + ".shp", "utf-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile" )
```